# How can I tell a password manager which system to save a username/password for?

Tags: idp, password-manager, password-autofill

###### Question

How can a webform explicitly tell the browser or password manager which system a username and password are to be remembered for?

###### Context

I design an authentication system that offers multiple identity providers, and most of our users have accounts on more than one identity provider (IDP). These IDPs are on different subdomains (but I'd rather not limit answers to that, if possible). A username is only unique within an IDP, not across all IDPs.

###### This has led to some usability problems

1. The password manager may save a username and password as the primary domain (example.com) or inappropriate domains (subdomain1.example.com) instead of the appropriate secondary domain (subdomain4.example.com). This choice is then impossible to differentiate from other options sharing the same username.

   [image: Safari's password manager saves one credential set for too many subdomains]

   It also leads to second-order usability problems described in *[How can I tell a password manager which username/password to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060061)*.
2. The password manager may give options of which password to overwrite but suggest only one username and password out of many, and the wrong one at that, requiring the user to search through the password store for the matching one.
3. When a user changes their password, the password manager may overwrite the wrong password in its store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell a password manager which username/password to autofill with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060061/how-can-i-tell-a-password-manager-which-username-password-to-autofill-with)

Comment: Reposting an already closed question is not acceptable conduct here.

Comment: @KenWhite, it was closed by mods because it was two questions in one. Now it's two separate questions. This is not reposting a closed question. If you think the other question should have answered this one, it never should have been closed in the first place.

Comment: It is reposting a closed question. The proper behavior when your post is closed is to edit it, not to post it again. Please review the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). This is a duplicate of the closed post that you created improperly.

Comment: Look again; I did edit it. If you have some other issue with it, describe the issue differently.

Comment: I said **edit your original question**. Do not post a new question, **edit the original question**. Is that clear enough for you?

Comment: I said that I edited it, and I mean it. Go look!

Answer (score 0):

Values saved by a password manager are related to field names. If each of these particular IdPs had a different password field name, then after one annoying hurdle (manually adding different password field values for differing IdPs), the single password manager entry would fill all the fields correctly leading to a simpler user experience.